# Using Rhino Mocks' Expect.Call for a Mock Property in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, rhino-mocks

The following C# code works just fine and the test passes as expected.

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using Rhino.Mocks;

namespace RhinoMocksTesting
{
    public interface ITesting
    {
        string Test { get; }
    }

    [TestFixture]
    public class MocksTest
    {

        [Test]
        public void TestMockExpect()
        {
            var mocks = new MockRepository();
            var testMock = mocks.StrictMock<ITesting>();
            Expect.Call(testMock.Test).Return("testing");
            mocks.ReplayAll();
            Assert.AreEqual("testing", testMock.Test);
        }
    }
}
```

However, trying to do the same thing in VB.NET won't even compile!

```
Imports NUnit.Framework
Imports Rhino.Mocks

Public Interface ITesting
    ReadOnly Property Test() As String
End Interface

<TestFixture()> _
Public Class MocksTest

    <Test()> _
    Public Sub TestMockExpect()
        Dim mocks = New MockRepository
        Dim testMock = mocks.StrictMock(Of ITesting)()
        Expect.Call(testMock.Test).Return("testing")
        mocks.ReplayAll()
        Assert.AreEqual("testing", testMock.Test)
    End Sub

End Class
```

The `Expect.Call` line produces the following build error: "Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Expect' accepts this number of arguments."

What is the proper way to use `Expect.Call` with a mocked property in VB.NET? I've seen a couple posts that say Rhino Mocks works better in VB10, but I'm stuck with Visual Studio 2008 for this current project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
Rhino.Mocks.Expect.Call(testMock.Test).Return("testing")
```

[Source](http://ayende.com/wiki/Rhino+mocks+3.5+and+VB.Net+the+AAA+syntax.ashx)

> Now we switch to Rhino mocks 3.5 and
>   see that we get an error on Expect
>   saying that the signature is not
>   correct. No worry this is because it
>   is choosing the wrong Expect. It is
>   namely trying to use the extension
>   method there. Just add Rhino.Mocks.
>   before the Expect and all is well
>   again. Look how the imports doesn't do
>   the same thing.

Comment: Wow. Thanks! I'm glad it was that simple.